# Differ HTML Nodes with same class name in C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am using `HTMLAgilityPack` to parse the HTML of a Website.

The Problem is: `There are two nodes with class "price"`. I can differ them by checking the `DOM`. So 3 levels above, the price I want has parent node with class `product-top`, and the node I DON'T want has class `advertisement` 3 levels above.

like this:

```
<div class="product-top">
    <div class="xy">
        <div class="zz">
            <div class="price">THIS IS WHAT I WANT>
close all

<div class="advertisement">
    <div class="xy2">
        <div class="zz2">
            <div class="price">THIS IS WHAT I DO NOT WANT>
close all
```

How can I access the Node from the first example using `HTMLAgilityPack` in C#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Parse first for either product-top or advertisement.  Then from resulting element than get price.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following XPath expression:

```
//div[@class='product-top']//div[@class='price']
```

Or if you want specifically 3 levels above:

```
//div[@class='product-top']/div/div/div[@class='price']
```